# Search for multiple values in xml column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

This is my table

```
BasketId(int)   BasketName(varchar) BasketFruits(xml)
1       Gold        <FRUITS><FID>1</FID><FID>2</FID><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID><FID>5</FID><FID>6</FID></FRUITS>
2       Silver      <FRUITS><FID>1</FID><FID>2</FID><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID></FRUITS>
3       Bronze      <FRUITS><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID><FID>5</FID></FRUITS>
```

I need to search for the basket which has `FID` values 1 and 3
so that in this case i would get **Gold** and **Silver**

Although i've reached to the result where i can search for a SINGLE FID value like **1**
using this code:

```
declare @fruitId varchar(10);
set @fruitId=1;
select * from Baskets
WHERE BasketFruits.exist('//FID/text()[contains(.,sql:variable("@fruitId"))]') = 1
```

HAD it been T-SQL i would have used the **IN Clause** like this

```
SELECT * FROM Baskets where FID in (1,3)
```

Any help/workaround appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option would be to add another exist the where clause.

```
declare @fruitId1 int;
set @fruitId1=1;

declare @fruitId2 int;
set @fruitId2=3;

select *
from @Test
where
  BasketFruits.exist('/FRUITS/FID[.=sql:variable("@fruitId1")]')=1 and
  BasketFruits.exist('/FRUITS/FID[.=sql:variable("@fruitId2")]')=1
```

Another version would be to use both variables in the xquery statement, counting the hits.

```
select * 
from @Test
where BasketFruits.value(
  'count(distinct-values(/FRUITS/FID[.=(sql:variable("@fruitId1"),sql:variable("@fruitId2"))]))', 'int') = 2
```

The two queries above will work just fine if you know how many FID parameters you are going to use when you write the query. If you are in a situation where the number of FID's vary you could use something like this instead.

```
declare @FIDs xml = '<FID>1</FID><FID>3</FID>'

;with cteParam(FID) as
(
  select T.N.value('.', 'int')
  from @FIDs.nodes('FID') as T(N)
)  
select T.BasketName
from @Test as T
  cross apply T.BasketFruits.nodes('/FRUITS/FID') as F(FID)
  inner join cteParam as p
    on F.FID.value('.', 'int') = P.FID
group by T.BasketName
having count(T.BasketName) = (select count(*) from cteParam)
```

Build the @FIDs variable as an XML to hold the values you want to use in the query.

You can test the last query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101600/relational-division-with-xquery

Comment: Excellent work!! Was looking for this answer for a long long time. Great work Mikael Eriksson. You're the man!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more involved than I hoped it would be - but this solution works.

Basically, I'm using a CTE (Common Table Expression) which breaks up the table and cross joins all values from the `<FID>` nodes to the basket names.

From that CTE, I select those baskets that contain both a value of `1` and `3`.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (BasketID INT, BasketName VARCHAR(20), BasketFruits XML)

INSERT INTO @TEST
VALUES(1, 'Gold', '<FRUITS><FID>1</FID><FID>2</FID><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID><FID>5</FID><FID>6</FID></FRUITS>'),
(2, 'Silver', '<FRUITS><FID>1</FID><FID>2</FID><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID></FRUITS>'),
(3, 'Bronze', '<FRUITS><FID>3</FID><FID>4</FID><FID>5</FID></FRUITS>')

;WITH IDandFID AS
(
SELECT
    t.BasketID,
    t.BasketName,
    FR.FID.value('(.)[1]', 'int') AS 'FID'
FROM @Test t
CROSS APPLY basketfruits.nodes('/FRUITS/FID') AS FR(FID)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BasketName
FROM 
    IDandFID i1
WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM IDandFID i2 WHERE i1.BasketID = i2.BasketID AND i2.FID = 1)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM IDandFID i3 WHERE i1.BasketID = i3.BasketID AND i3.FID = 3)
```

Running this query, I do get the expected output of:

```
BasketName
----------
Gold
Silver
```

Comment: This solution works without a doubt. Great Job!
However, if the number of values to be matched for increases like now if i want to search for Baskets with **FruitIds** 1,2 and 3, another EXISTS statement will have to be concatenated using dynamic queries.
Or i guess, i'd need to call this stored procedure in a while loop recursively...?

Comment: @nav: yes, I agree - the solution isn't perfect in that it's not "extensible" - but I cannot think of any other way just right now

Answer (score 0):

Is this too trivial?

```
SELECT * FROM Baskets WHERE BasketFruits LIKE '%<FID>1</FID>%' AND BasketFruits LIKE '%<FID>3</FID>%'
```