# Filter on more than one XML element

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

```
<Root>
    <Sub>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Sub>
</Root>
```

I know I can do a

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column.exist('/Root/Sub[Name="a" and Value="1"]') = 1
```

but how do I filter on both Name/Value pairs? a/1 and b/2?

Comment: Similar question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162273/search-for-multiple-values-in-xml-column-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(column.exist('/Root/Sub[Name="a" and Value="1"]') = 1 OR
(column.exist('/Root/Sub[Name="b" and Value="2"]') = 1)`

Note the additional parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

This will work as expected:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableName
 WHERE XMLColumnName.Exist('/Root/Sub[Id = "IdValue"][LimitType = "LimitTypeName"]') = 1
```